# Scraping data from multiple website and merge them to one file

Tags: r, web-scraping

I would like to scrape data from several sources, for example: https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty https://reality.idnes.cz/s/prodej/byty/
https://www.bezrealitky.cz/vypis/nabidka-prodej/byt
I would be interested in the following information for these sources:
apartments_pages
apartments_price
apartments_area
apartments_floor
apartments_owner
apartments_avaliable
I would like to combine this individual information into one file (csv)

After the previous advice from Tom Hoel, I tried the following code, which worked perfectly for the page https://www.bezrealitky.cz/vypis/nabidka-prodej/byt.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


get_listings <- function(page) {
  listings <-
    str_c("https://www.bezrealitky.cz/vypis/nabidka-prodej/byt?page=", page) %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_elements(".PropertyCard_propertyCard--disable-link-mask__E6BVo")
  
  tibble(
    title = listings %>%
      html_element(".text-subheadline") %>%
      html_text2(),
    price = listings %>%
      html_element(".mb-0.mt-3 span") %>%
      html_text2(),
    size = listings %>%
      html_element(
        ".FeaturesList_featuresListItem__SugGi+ .FeaturesList_featuresListItem__SugGi"
      ) %>%
      html_text2(),
    rooms = listings %>%
      html_element(".FeaturesList_featuresListItem__SugGi:nth-child(1)") %>%
      html_text2(),
    area = listings %>%
      html_element(".text-uppercase") %>%
      html_text2(),
    url = listings %>%
      html_node(".PropertyCard_propertyCardHeadline__y3bhA") %>%
      html_children() %>%
      html_attr("href")
  )
}

byty =  map_dfr(1:1, get_listings)


write.csv(byty, "byty.csv")
```

When I wanted to use the same principle on other sites, it no longer worked and I did not receive any data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


get_listings <- function(page) {
  listings <-
    str_c("https://www.bezrealitky.cz/vypis/nabidka-prodej/byt?page=", page) %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_elements(".PropertyCard_propertyCard--disable-link-mask__E6BVo")
  
  tibble(
    title = listings %>%
      html_element(".text-subheadline") %>%
      html_text2(),
    price = listings %>%
      html_element(".mb-0.mt-3 span") %>%
      html_text2(),
    size = listings %>%
      html_element(
        ".FeaturesList_featuresListItem__SugGi+ .FeaturesList_featuresListItem__SugGi"
      ) %>%
      html_text2(),
    rooms = listings %>%
      html_element(".FeaturesList_featuresListItem__SugGi:nth-child(1)") %>%
      html_text2(),
    url = listings %>%
      html_node(".PropertyCard_propertyCardHeadline__y3bhA") %>%
      html_children() %>%
      html_attr("href")
      );
  get_reality_idnes <- function(strana) {
    listings <-
      str_c("https://reality.idnes.cz/s/prodej/byty/?page=1", strana) %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_elements(".c-products__inner")
    
    tibble(
      title = listings %>%
        html_nodes(".c-products__title") %>% 
        html_text2(),
      price = listings %>%
        html_element(".c-products__price") %>%
        html_text2(),
      info = listings %>%
        html_element(".c-products__info") %>%
        html_text2(),
      url = listings %>%
        html_nodes(".c-products__link") %>% 
        html_attr("href")
    )
  }
}

byty_bezrealitky =  map_dfr(1:1, get_listings)
byty_idnes = map_dfr(1:1, get_reality_idnes)
```

I then tried nesting the same function inside myself to trigger it in one call, but that didn't work either.

I've probably been all over the web and can't find anywhere on how to do this

[image]

Does anyone know how this could possibly be done? Thanks for any answers

Comment: Nothing created inside a function is available outside of said function unless explicitly returned by that function and captured by the calling environment. There is the notion of "side-effect" where your function can `assign` those objects into the calling or global environment; many seasoned programmers avoid doing that for many reasons, notably that it typically breaks reproducibility, makes troubleshooting at times significantly problematic, and (in my opinion) I want no function to create or update objects in my envir (exception: pkgs like `data.table`, but that's "by-definition").

Comment: Well thank you. So what would you recommend to me, how to do it, some instructions or something like that? I am a beginner in this. For example, I based this on a YouTube video

Comment: Perhaps add your `data.frame(..)` command to _inside_ the function and return that frame from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Scraping the first `1:5` pages into a tibble

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


get_listings <- function(page) {
  listings <-
    str_c("https://www.bezrealitky.cz/vypis/nabidka-prodej/byt?page=", page) %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_elements(".PropertyCard_propertyCard--disable-link-mask__E6BVo")
  
  tibble(
    title = listings %>%
      html_element(".text-subheadline") %>%
      html_text2(),
    price = listings %>%
      html_element(".mb-0.mt-3 span") %>%
      html_text2(),
    size = listings %>%
      html_element(
        ".FeaturesList_featuresListItem__SugGi+ .FeaturesList_featuresListItem__SugGi"
      ) %>%
      html_text2(),
    rooms = listings %>%
      html_element(".FeaturesList_featuresListItem__SugGi:nth-child(1)") %>%
      html_text2(),
    area = listings %>%
      html_element(".text-uppercase") %>%
      html_text2(),
    url = listings %>%
      html_node(".PropertyCard_propertyCardHeadline__y3bhA") %>%
      html_children() %>%
      html_attr("href")
  )
}

map_dfr(1:5, get_listings)

# A tibble: 75 × 6
   title                                        price size  rooms area  url  
   <chr>                                        <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 Novodvorská, Praha - Braník                  4 70… 41 m² 2+kk  Prod… http…
 2 Praha - Nové Město                           8 69… 39 m² 1+kk  Prod… http…
 3 Svatopluka Čecha, Brno - Královo Pole, Jiho… 6 50… 66 m² 3+1   Prod… http…
 4 Rožnov pod Radhoštěm, Zlínský kraj           4 10… 74 m² 3+1   Prod… http…
 5 Milovice nad Labem, Středočeský kraj         4 20… 86 m² 3+kk  Prod… http…
 6 Praha - Podolí                               6 99… 53 m² 2+kk  Prod… http…
 7 Praha - Strašnice                            6 69… 64 m² 2+1   Prod… http…
 8 Praha - Letňany                              4 89… 43 m² 2+kk  Prod… http…
 9 Praha - Modřany                              8 19… 92 m² 4+kk  Prod… http…
10 Praha - Malá Strana                          12 9… 53 m² 2+kk  Prod… http…
# … with 65 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```